# My content wont go into a wrapper

Tags: html, css

I can't get my content to go into a wrapper, it just shows on the left side

```
<div id="middle">   
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="image_rose"><img src="assets/rose.jpg"/></div>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci.</p>
    <img src="assets/leef.png" />
    <p>Text Input:</p>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    background-color:#666666;
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
}

#middle{
    background-color:#666;
    width:900px;
    float:left;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It won't go into a wrapper?" If the #middle is floated, it won't "wrap around" the content, unless it has a specific height or you have cleared the float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting your content and wrapper into #middle, which floats left.  wrapper is the same size and middle, so will just site on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear your float as shown below:
clear:both

Answer (score 1):

If the content is showing beyond the div, you might try adding an `overflow: hidden;` or a different overflow setting to that specific div in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout for centering your middle content

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <div id="middle">

   </div>

 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
width:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

#middle
{
 margin:0 auto;
 width: 600px;
}
```